# Save CheckBox state in app

Tags: android, checkbox

I have checkbox in my android app. My checkbox is checked when app's first run. 
What if user disable checkbox? I don't want to save preferences in my app.

Every time `isChecked` is true for my arrangement. After user change checkbox How can I save the state of the checkbox?

**xml:**

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/remember_me"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF297AA6"
    android:checked="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Here my activity code - Always `isChecked` true from my xml;

```
if (mCheckBox.isChecked()) {
    remembername = preferences.getString("user", "");
    rememberpassword = preferences.getString("pasword", "");
    user.setText(remembername);
    parola.setText(rememberpassword);
}
```

Comment: If you want to preserve state of checkbox after application closes and gets relaunched, then you **will have to use either shared preferences or database**. Why don't you want to save preferences?

Comment: do u want to implement remember me functionality of user login preference?

Comment: Yes @Karan ı want to remember me functioanlity

Comment: see my answer, it's your solution. :-)

Comment: But I want to make checkbox checked when first launch. And if user change the checkbox not checked after first launched. I want to make checkbox not checked when second launch.

Comment: I have made edit in my answer, check it and let me know if it resolved or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in your checkbox `onclick` method :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = this.getPreferences(0).edit();
if(cbRememberMe.isChecked()){ 
    checkPreference = true;
    editor.putString("savename", etUserName.getText().toString().trim());
    editor.putString("savepassword", etPassword.getText().toString().trim());
    editor.putBoolean("check", checkPreference);
    editor.commit();
    Log.i("Remember Me", "checked,preference added");
}
else{
    checkPreference = false;
    editor.putString("savename", "");
    editor.putString("savepassword", "");
    editor.putBoolean("check", checkPreference);
    editor.commit();
    Log.i("Remember Me", "Unchecked, preferences removed");
}
```

In your `onCreate()` method, write below lines:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getPreferences(0);
strUserName = prefs.getString("savename", null);
if (strUserName != null) {
    etUserName.setText(strUserName);
}
strPassword = prefs.getString("savepassword", null);
if (strPassword != null) {
    etPassword.setText(strPassword);
}
rememberMe = prefs.getBoolean("check", true);  
if (rememberMe == true) {
    cbRememberMe.setChecked(true);  
}
```

Comment: Can not resolve getPreferences in "this.getPreferences(0).edit()"

Comment: I use preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

Comment: write that in your Activity onCreate() method or changed to getActivity().getPreferences(0).edit().

Comment: Your code looks like make my aim. But I can not understand something. What is rememberMe ? in last section.

Comment: rememberMe is a boolean variable.

Comment: getPreference is the method and checkPrefrence is a boolean variable.